# Connect to MySQL Database on cPanel Server Externally from Heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cpanel

I am using the Heroku app to host a facebook application since Facebook is changing how they have their applications set up, again. However I need to connect to the MySQL Externally from my cPanel VPS and I am not able to connect correctly. I have tried using the `darkprospect.net`(host domain), `ultimate-battle-online.com` (primary domain of user) and `184.154.20.170` as well as those plus the combination of added port `3306` and none have worked. I previously needed to make sure that I added the right domain to the right file but right now it's just not connecting. Right now get this error when using `mysql_connect()` function:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

Again, thank you for any ideas that you may have!

**EDIT**: I found out that it was an issue with the buildpack that is the default for PHP apps, since I develop on a VPS with PHP 5.4.7 I was using parameters that were tuned for it and were not very supportive on their bundle of vanilla PHP and Apache.

Comment: With cPanel there is an option to allow certain hosts to access your database. The default is just to allow localhost request (much more secure). Within the MySQL part of cPanel you should find an option to allow external access

Comment: I am also trying to find out what I need to do on Heroku side to access my own VPS.

Comment: I am able to connect via Sequel Pro the SQL connection app for Mac easily and via mysql executable as well on my machine, however I am not getting anything from the app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a new Heroku buildpack that was able to support all of the features that my application was needing. Because I was developing on my VPS in PHP 5.4.7 my configurations were designed for more of the new features and with the Heroku's basic Buildpack only having PHP 5.3.10 there were unseen errors in background logs that were halting the connection process. Additionally CSF Firewall was configured only for UDP income 3306 and I was able to add it to UTP as well and that seemed to resolve the Connection Timed Out error that was the final error after I made a better buildpack for myself.